# Sharing MongoDB to localhost

Tags: mongodb, localhost, share, database

How to connect to MongoDB in the other computer in a local network?

I have already changed the IP just like phpmyadmin mySQL, but it won't work.
How can I connect to mongodb on another computer?

Comment: Use `mongo REMOTE_IP` eg: `mongo 192.168.x.y`

Comment: Make sure your MongoDB doesn't bind to only localhost (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed MongoDb by binary files then it will not bind with local host. So any mongdb server can be connect remotely. If you install with apt like then see its config file at `/etc/mongod.conf` and comment the bind-ip line.

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Now restart it. 
for connect remotely use --host variable.

```
mongo --host=192.168.10.123
```